# How to target an element using multiple class names with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am working in Wordpress and I was able to target an element to change some of the CSS with this exact code:

```
body.admin-bar .mobmenu{
top:140px;
}
```

I need to also target this exact element with Javascript to change it's CSS properties after the user has scrolled down the page to reset it back to: top:0px

How would I target this using Javascript since it's multiple class names? I can't assign it an ID

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the only element with this classname.

You can use the document [query selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```js
const myElement = document.querySelector("body.admin-bar.mobmenu")
```

Should do the trick

Comment: doesn't seem to work it's returning 
(index):1761 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at window.onwheel ((index):1761:14)
in the console

this is my full code any obvious reason why might not be working?

const mobilebar = document.querySelector('body.admin-bar.mobmenu');



window.onwheel = e => {
  if(e.deltaY >= 0){
    // Scrolling Down with mouse
   mobilebar.classList.add('scrolleddown');
  } else {
    // Scrolling Up with mouse
    console.log('Scroll Up');
  }
}

the class has already been set and should before this code

Comment: Can you show me the snippet of code where you implement the fix